# How to split video output signal from 1 PC to 40 projectors

Tags: video, hdmi, video-streaming, projector, splitter

I am thinking of implementing this by daisy-chaining multiple splitters but I am not sure if it will work.

Does anyone know of a cost-effective solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: You certainly can't do this on the PC itself, so it's off-topic. I don't see why chaining multiple splitters shouldn't work...

Comment: I'm afraid of signal attenuation and I'd like to do some research before running off and buying a bunch of expensive splitters that might not meet my requirements. The cost of the cables run up to quite a lot too.

Comment: Splitters must be active, so you needn't worry about signal attenuation. You need to make sure to use powered splitters, though. And yes, wiring up that many splitters is a nightmare no matter how you go about it. So a network based solution, possibly even WLAN if possible in your situation, with a multicast stream would be a lot better (non-multicast will saturate WLAN). If it's LAN instead of WLAN, you need a big switch and lots of LAN cables instead of HDMI splitters and HDMI cables...

Answer (score 2):

You could output the video as a stream on one pc, and play this stream with something like a raspberry pi attached to the 40 projectors? In this case, every projector would have a raspberry pi attached to it.

Comment: That might be a good idea actually. What software would you use to stream? I would need to stream as close to real-time as possible. Ideally through LAN without an Internet connection.